# Maven project configuration to generate short form of Git commit id that is set by Jenkins Git Plugin?

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

Jenkins Git Plugin sets `GIT_COMMIT` environment variable with Git commit SHA1 id which is 40 characters long. Because I want to use Git commit id as part of my version string, I need to shorten it to 6 characters(e.g. 1.0.0-d5e8dc). Maven captures `GIT_COMMIT` environment variable and I somehow should shorten it in Maven.

Comment: Why not use git-commit-id-plugin, that is able to fetch the info with or without jenkins variables? see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37476898/365237)

Comment: I did not figured out this plug-in, thank you. It would be a better/only(?) solution, if I did not use Jenkins. In my case, using `maven-git-commit-id-plugin` only to fetch short git commit id seems more complex. `maven-git-commit-id-plugin` has great capability, though. It helps you bundle lots of git repository information into the application binary that can be used at run-time easily.

Answer (score 0):

`build-helper-maven-plugin` with proper regular expression worked for me:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>regex-property</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>regex-property</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <!-- 
              This property will have short Git commit id. 
            -->
            <name>short-git-commit-id</name>
            <!-- 
              Jenkins Git Plugin sets GIT_COMMIT environment
              variable which is 40 characters long SHA1 value.
            -->
            <value>${GIT_COMMIT}</value>
            <!-- 
              To get the first 6 characters of Git commit id, we 
              cut last 40-6=34 characters off. 
            --> 
            <regex>.{34}$</regex>
            <replacement></replacement>
            <failIfNoMatch>true</failIfNoMatch>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```